# Socket emit data received by ajax with Node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Server side: I receive user list by ajax and Im trying to emit it by socket, but only to the same client.
Something like this

```
io.sockets.emit("users list", {users: users, me : req.me});//This work, but to all users

socket.emit("users list", {users: users, me : req.me}); //Im trying something like this
```

The code

```
//Receive user list
    app.post('/', function(request, response){
        response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost'); //To allow response
        var req = JSON.parse(request.body.data);
        if(typeof req != "object") {
            response.send({status: false, msg: "Error on load user list"});
        } else {
            socket.id = req.me.id;
            req.users.data.forEach(function(user) {
                if(users[user.id] == null)
                    users[user.id] = user;
            });

            //io.sockets.emit("users list", {users: users, me : req.me});//This work, but to all users
            socket.emit("users list", {users: users, me : req.me}); //Im trying something like this
        }
        response.send({status: true, msg: ""});// echo the result back
    });
```

I also wanna know if there are some best way to do this...

Comment: But why would you send something to a client that you just received from the same client ?

Comment: My Node app is inside and iframe (with the client). PHP (top frame) send a request and Node (iframe) loads the page with the users list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending data to an specific socket, like this:

io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit("users list", {users: users, me : req.me});